# Multiple file download

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, download

ASP.NET/VB.NET web application.

Currently I'm creating a Word document and streaming it to the user. The browser handles this great with an "open/save" dialog, etc...

Basically the webform has a multi-select listbox. They select one or MORE documents and click the "Generate/Download" button. Works great for a single file. But multiple files doesn't work. Here's part of my code....

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", Convert.ToString("attachment; filename=") & DocFileNameDestination)
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-length", finalDocumentStream.ToArray().Length.ToString())
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-word"
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(finalDocumentStream.ToArray())
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush()
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
```

Question: How can I allow the user to **download all selected files at one time**. I would prefer a really simple solution. (Even if I have to create a zip... only if easier.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is VB not asp, but it might be useful to you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35787/VB-NET-Background-File-Downloader

Comment: I would personally just toss them into a `For Each` loop to cycle through the list and download each file in sequence.

Comment: @Zack The problem is when the "Open/Save" dialog appears in the browser the code is already continuing and another dialog doesn't appear. Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can download them one at a time in a loop. If you want to download them all at once, you can download each one in a separate thread by starting a backgroundworker for each file in the loop.

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide a link or example for the backgroundworker?